# Configuring wadl2java plugin for gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to use the gradle plugin http://cxf.apache.org/docs/overview.html to generate java code from a `wadl` file. The dependency seems to be resolved correctly but when I'm invoking the `wadl2java` I get `Could not find method wadl2java()`. So I'm wondering why I'm getting this error(as it should exist, looking in other maven and command line examples of this plugin) and how this plugin is supposed to used? Any help is really appreciated.

Have tried to do some research in this field but there doesn't seem to be that much information about this.

Snippets from my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {  
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.apache.cxf:cxf-wadl2java-plugin:3.1.5"
    }
}

// Results in 'Could not find method error'
wadl2java {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is late, but since I also could not find an answer on SO, I'm putting down the solution here.

This runs the command line version of the same tool. What you tried is the maven plugin which is not supported in gradle.

(You probably dont need all the dependencies I've added.)

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'javax.xml', name: 'jaxrpc', version: '1.1'
compile group: 'wsdl4j', name: 'wsdl4j', version: '1.6.3'
compile group: 'javax.xml.soap', name: 'saaj-api', version: '1.3.5'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7'
compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws', version: '3.1.10'
compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty', version: '3.1.10'
compile 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools:3.1.10'
compile group: 'org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils', name: 'cxf-xjc-runtime', version: '3.1.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-wadl2java-plugin', version: '3.1.10'
compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-tools-wadlto', version: '3.1.10'
compile("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.12")
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'}

project.ext {
wadlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/resources")
generatedWadlDir = file("build/generated-sources")
wadlsToGenerate = [['src/main/resources/your_wadl_file.wadl']]}

task wadl2Java() {
println "Deleting auto generated files.."

if( !project.buildDir.exists() ) {
    project.buildDir.mkdirs()
}

def subdir = new File(project.buildDir, "generated-sources")

if( !subdir.exists() ) {
    subdir.mkdirs()
}

file( subdir ).list().each{
    f -> delete "${subdir}/${f}"
}

if (!wadlDir.listFiles()) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    inputs.files wadlDir.listFiles()
    outputs.files generatedWadlDir
    doLast {
        wadlsToGenerate.each { argsin ->
            argsin.add(argsin.size - 1, '-d')
            argsin.add(argsin.size - 1, generatedWadlDir)
            javaexec {
                classpath = configurations.runtime
                main = 'org.apache.cxf.tools.wadlto.WADLToJava'
                args = argsin
                systemProperties = ['exitOnFinish': 'TRUE']
            }
        }

        println "Copy auto generated files.."

        copy {
            from generatedWadlDir
            into 'src/main/java'
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, however if you're interested in another approach to this problem you can check out my own answer how I finally did it.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the `wadl2java.bat` directly command line in an own task.

```
task wadl2java(type:Exec) {
    description = 'Generate java files from WADL file using the wadl2java tool'
    workingDir = "$projectDir/apache-cxf-3.1.5/bin/"
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'wadl2java.bat', '-verbose', '-p', "com.your.package",  '-d', "$projectDir/src/main/java", "-xjc -b $path/to/your/bindings" , "$path/to/your/wadl"
}
```